# (node:15016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: adb: Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, adb

I have problems trying to run example app 'tabs' with ionic cordova in the emulator or device.
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and have installe java sdk, android studio, node.js and everything. I need some help because I can find info about this issue.

I got this console messages:

```
Skipping build...
Built the following apk(s): 
    /home/irene/test/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
Using apk: /home/irene/test/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
Package name: io.ionic.starter
(node:15016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: adb: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
adb: failed to install /home/irene/test/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package io.ionic.starter signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!]
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/home/irene/test/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:346:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:567:12)
(node:15016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15016) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My ionic info is:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.4, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/irene/Android/Sdk/)
   NodeJS            : v8.10.0 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm               : 3.5.2
   OS                : Linux 4.15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package io.ionic.starter signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!]

> your package name now "io.ionic.starter"

your build is successful but you have already installed an apk with the same packge name  so change your app package name inside cofig.xml line no- 2

```
<widget id="app.newapkname" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

> Uninstall the app from your device first, then try again.

The problem you are experiencing usually happens if a build of the app was installed on the phone using a different computer or a different development environment (eg; if you reinstalled all of your software)